# php "glob" pattern help

Tags: php, html, xml

I have a directory with sitemaps, which all end with a number.

I have an automatic sitemap generator script which needs to count all sitemaps in a folder using glob.

Currently I am stuck here.

What I need is to count all sitemap files which has a number in them, so I don't count the ones without any numbers.

For instance, in my root I have a sitemap.xml file, then I also have sitemap1.xml, sitemap2.xml, sitemap3.xml etc...

I need to use glob to only return true when the filename contains a number like "sitemap1.xml".

Is this possible?

```
$nr_of_sitemaps = count(glob(Sitemaps which contains numbers in their filenames));
```

Thanks

Comment: Afaik, no, `glob` won't help you. YOu'll have to retrieve all the names and check them in a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To glob for files ending in `<digit>.xml` you can use a pattern like:

```
*[0-9].xml
```

So to count the matches, the PHP might look like:

```
$count = count(glob('/path/to/files/*[0-9].xml'));
```

If you want super-fine control (moreso than glob can give) over the matching files, you could use a general pattern then use [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep) to filter the resulting array to precisely what you want.

```
$count = count(
    preg_grep(
        '#(?:^|/)sitemap\d{1,3}\.xml$#',
        glob('/path/to/files/sitemap*.xml')
    )
);
```

See also: http://cowburn.info/2010/04/30/glob-patterns/

Comment: So in my case: glob('sitemap[0-9].xml') ? This must work even if there are several digits, like "sitemap43.xml".

Comment: No, `[0-9]` will only match a single digit. If you want to cater for variable numbers of digits, go with my regex suggestion or perhaps `sitemap*[0-9].xml` if false positives won't also match that.

Comment: +1 for preg_grep. Very useful and very much underrated function.